# Google Play Games, backing up data, Drive deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, google-drive-api, google-play-games

I'm just coming to the end of writing my first game, last thing to do is enable backing up the user's game. I have leaderboards and achievements implemented fine, and all Google's docs say I should be saving games to Drive using `.requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)` which upon trying leads me to find that it's no longer going to work in 2 months.

Digging further, I found this line from Google: "Support for storing and syncing in the app data folder will likely be removed from Drive in the future."

I'm still learning all this as I go, and I'm using Kotlin (I don't know Java). Can anyone point me in the right direction to where I should be looking to backup users game data if the way Google suggests isn't going to work very soon?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, not sure how else to phrase it, Problem: I've tried to implement "Save Game" as recommended by Google, only to find Google's Android Studio says it's deprecated. Done to solve it: I don't know how to solve it which is why I'm here

Comment: Would you be happy with saving data locally to [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)?

Comment: Hi Markus, I already use sharedprefs, it's those I want to backup to the cloud in some way and the auto backup service doesn't work even 50% of the time in my experience, it never restores after a cache clean or re-install (even if it says it was backed up overnight)

Answer (score 0):

Google is deprecating the Google Drive Android API in favor of the Google Drive REST API. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/sync-google-drive-files-to-apps-using-the-drive-rest-api-bidding-farewell-to-the-drive-android-api) is the best starting point for implementing that in android that I could find.